# XML Serialization of HTML

Tags: c#, html, xml-serialization, cdata

**Okay this one DID it! Thanks to all of you!**

```
public class Result
{
    public String htmlEscaped
    {
        set;
        get;
    }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public String htmlValue
    { set; get; }

    [XmlElement("htmlValue")]
    public XmlCDataSection htmlValueCData
    {
        get
        {
            XmlDocument _dummyDoc = new XmlDocument();
            return _dummyDoc.CreateCDataSection(htmlValue);
        }
        set { htmlValue = (value != null) ? value.Data : null; }
    }
}

    Result r = new Result();
    r.htmlValue = ("<b>Hello</b>");
    r.htmlEscaped = ("<b>Hello</b>");
    XmlSerializer xml = new XmlSerializer(r.GetType());
    TextWriter file = new StreamWriter(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\results\\result.xml", false, System.Text.Encoding.Default);
    xml.Serialize(file, r);
    file.Close();
```

RESULT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252"?>
<Result xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <htmlEscaped>&lt;b&gt;Hello&lt;/b&gt;</htmlEscaped>
  <htmlValue><![CDATA[<b>Hello</b>]]></htmlValue>
</Result>
```

As you can see, after CDATA is return type, no more escaped html in XML file on filesystem.
The JSON Serialization isn't working anymore, but this can be fixed with a little type extention.

---

QUESTION WAS:

Maybe someone knows how to make do it...

I have this Class:

```
public class Result
{
    public String htmlValue
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

I use this to serialize it to XML

```
Result res = new Result();
res.htmlValue = "<p>Hello World</p>";
XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(res.GetType());
TextWriter w = new StreamWriter(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\result.xml", false, System.Text.Encoding.Default);
s.Serialize(w, res);
w.Close();
```

Works fine i get this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252"?>
<Result xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <htmlValue>&lt;b&gt;Hello World&lt;/b&gt;</htmlValue>
</Result>
```

What can do i have to change to get this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252"?>
<Result xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <htmlValue><![CDATA[<b>Hello World</b>]]></htmlValue>
</Result>
```

I've already searched but I can't find anything. The type of htmlValue
have to stay String, because of other Serialisations JSON, etc.

Tricky one... Thanks in advance for suggestions

- HTML is correct in String within C#. Why decode or encode?
- XmlSerializer saved the HTML escaped to XML file.
- Don't use C# for consuming.

Is external tool which accept this:

```
<htmlValue><![CDATA[<b>Hello World</b>]]></htmlValue>
```

but not

```
<htmlValue>&lt;b&gt;Hello World&lt;/b&gt;</htmlValue>
```

I do the same with JSON Serializer, in file on hard drive the HTML is saved correct.
Why and where to use HTTP Utility to prevent that? And how to get `<![CDATA[ ]]>` around it.

Can you give a code sample?
Are there any other Serializer than the C# own one?

I've found this Link [.NET XML Serialization of CDATA ATTRIBUTE](http://blogit.create.pt/blogs/marcosilva/archive/2008/11/23/.NET-XML-Serialization-of-CDATA-ATTRIBUTE.aspx)  from Marco André Silva, which does I need to do, but it's different, how to include this without changing Types?

Comment: Why do you care? The two are identical semantically.

Comment: Becourse the tool consuming it, doesn't like it. On first on it shows the HTML Text. On 2nd it shows "Hello World" bold. I can't change the consuming tool.

Comment: Then there's something else wrong with the tool, since you don't have `<b>Hello World</b>` so it shouldn't be bold.

Comment: John "If the tool accepts the CDATA version but not the escaped version, then the tool has a fatal bug that needs to be fixed. The two are sematically identical XML. Perhaps the tool does not understand XML? Beyond that, I don't understand your question. Also, C# is a programming language. It does not have any serializers at all. You appear to be referring to .NET serializers, and you happen to be using them from the C# programming language."

Right, but why is there anyway a CDATA Tag on XML Standard? If there is another way of creating XML Files in C# from Classes.. open for any Solution.

Comment: ups...<p> should be <b>, fixed in question. happend on creating the example, problem is still the same. Consuming Tool can't be changed it productive and company made it is gone!

Comment: I wasn't involved in the design of XML. :-) However, remember that XML stands for "eXtensible Markup Language". The primary use case was someone having plain text, and adding "markup" characters to it. If a person is creating XML from text, then being able to put a CDATA around existing text makes sense. CDATA was not created because programs need it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a simple trick to do achieve what you want. You just need to serialize a XmlCDataSection property instead of the string property :

(it's almost the same as John's suggestion, but a bit simpler...)

```
public class Result
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    public String htmlValue
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    private static XmlDocument _dummyDoc;

    [XmlElement("htmlValue")]
    public XmlCDataSection htmlValueCData
    {
        get { return _dummyDoc.CreateCDataSection(htmlValue); }
        set { htmlValue = (value != null) ? value.Data : null; }
    }
}
```

Comment: My "suggestion" was from a case where the OP needed CDATA as a text value.

Comment: comes out empty, only XML Header. Maybe [XmlIgnore] on htmlValue affects [XmlElement("htmlValue")]. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 0):

See "[CDATA serialization with XMLSerializer](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/thread/6f59a2c0-2f70-4f19-9210-c675bbdce48d)" for the same problem, and for the solution.

BTW, it seems to me that if the vendor no longer exists, it's time to use a different product. Possibly one that understands the XML specifications which have only existed for over a decade.

Comment: There was an error reflecting type. 

[XmlElement("node", typeof(XmlCDataSection))]
        public string htmlValue
        {
            get; set;
        }

Return needs to be String because of JSON Serializer.

Comment: I think you need to post some code. First you're talking about XML Serialization, now JSON serialization. I don't understand what problem  you're trying to solve.

Comment: I'm using already the JsonExSerializer, which does the job fine. I also need XML. Object > XML

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do? That's why I want you to post some code showing what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

It is my understanding that you need the XML to feed it to some utility. Do you also plan to use it to de-serialize the object?

If not then why do not do it yourself - serialize your object that is? Roundtrip object -> XML -> object is somewhat tricky, but the first part is not.