# Is there any C# attributes that prevents character conversion when a data member is serialized?

Tags: c#, serialization

I have an object that contains a string property, which returns a string that contains HTML tags:

```
[DataMember]
public string SomeProperty
{
    return "<HTMLTag>";
}
```

When this object is serialized by `DataContractJsonSerializer.WriteObject()`, the `'<'` and `'>'` characters are converted to `"&lt;"` and `"&gt;"`. Is there any attribute (or something else) that can prevent this from happening? I know `WriteRaw` will do the trick, but I can't change the `DataContractJsonSerializer.WriteObject()` is beyond my control. Thanks.

Comment: Writing `<HTMLTag>` into your serialized XML would make the XML invalid, because of missing closing tag.

Comment: It might sound funny, but *DataContractJsonSerializer* is indeed being derived from *XmlObjectSerializer*, which explains the observed behavior. Perhaps using Json.NET could be an alternative, if JSON (de)serialization is all you are looking for.

Comment: The returned string is just an example. I only care about the character conversion.

Comment: Similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1506499/xml-serialization-of-html

Comment: I have to use DataContractJsonSerializer.WriteObject(). I can't change it to anything else. It's beyond my control.

Comment: Can you explain your actual problem? Why is the default encoding a problem? The reading party should follow the same encoding rules as the writer, if you add exceptions (i.e. don't escape characters that should be escaped), you're breaking convention and probably other software.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [similar problem considered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2151956/can-a-json-string-contain-html-tags-with-it). Mentioning this, you can encode your HTML into different data, transfer and then decode.

Answer (score 0):

By using

```
string noEncoding = new XElement("foo", new XCData("a < b")).ToString();
```

This will produce

```
<foo><![CDATA[a < b]]></foo>
```